# High resolution and reasonable cost RGB satellite images

Tags: imagery, color, satellite, mapping, colormap

I need to obtain high-resolution RGB satellite images with reasonable cost for Pakistan. The objective is to guide tourist on high-resolution GIS maps. Google Earth does not have very high resolution images for certain areas in Pakistan. Which satellites can provide very high-resolution images for this area?

Comment: I would check on the Open Data Stack Exchange for free data.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a lookt at [Planet](https://www.planet.com/products/planet-imagery/). They offer three different resolutions (1, 3 and 5m). You can get a free-trial and check if it fits your needs.

For the costs, maybe check this [conference paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326417596_Benchmark_of_Satellites_Image_Services_for_Precision_Agricultural_use) that does a benchmark of different satellites or this [pricing information](http://www.landinfo.com/satellite-imagery-pricing.html) for reference.